# How to Show loading image on Server Side Remote Validation

Tags: remote-validation

I Use Remote Validation in my Project and I want to show image when i write Email in textbox and when action call this image is show and when action return result then image is hide and it should be done by server side validation. Please Reply..

Comment: What kind of UI framework are you using?

Comment: I use Mvc3 UI framework. I have a textbox in which i enter email when action is call then loading image is shown and complete of action loading image should be hide.